# Graph API: reportDate attribute not available in getEmailActivityCounts

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, office365, usage-statistics

I have been using the getEmailActivityCounts(Beta version) in graph api for the past 3 years.
But recently facing issues on retrieving the reportDate in the graph data when JSON export type is used. Without reportDate, we couldn't map on which date the metrics count had happened.

Any help would be appreciated.

**Request** : [https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/reports/getEmailActivityCounts(period='D180')?$format=application/json](https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/reports/getEmailActivityCounts(period=%27D180%27)?$format=application/json)

**Response** : {
"reportRefreshDate": "2022-01-19",
"send": 3,
"receive": 14,
"read": null,
"meetingCreated": 0,
"meetingInteracted": null,
"reportPeriod": "180"
},
{
"reportRefreshDate": "2022-01-19",
"send": 1,
"receive": 1,
"read": null,
"meetingCreated": 0,
"meetingInteracted": null,
"reportPeriod": "180"
}

Thanks in Advance,
Maerona Wynn

Comment: Could you use reportRefreshDate instead of reportDate? It seems to me that both of them have the same value.

Comment: reportRefreshDate is different from reportDate. reportRefreshDate will be the date when the data is refreshed. reportDate is the date to map the metrics count